# Execute code block if condition or exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception

With exceptions being so central to idiomatic Python, is there a clean way to execute a particular code block if an expression evaluates to True **or** the evaluation of the expression raises an exception? By clean, I mean an easy-to-read, Pythonic, and not repeating the code block?

For example, instead of:

```
try:
    if some_function(data) is None:
        report_error('Something happened')
except SomeException:
    report_error('Something happened') # repeated code
```

can this be cleanly rewritten so that `report_error()` isn't written twice?

(Similar question: [How can I execute same code for a condition in try block without repeating code in except clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559765/how-can-i-execute-same-code-for-a-condition-in-try-block-without-repeating-code) but this is for a specific case where the exception can be avoided by a simple test within the if statement.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done relatively cleanly, although whether it can be considered good style is an open question.

```
def test(expression, exception_list, on_exception):
    try:
        return expression()
    except exception_list:
        return on_exception

if test(lambda: some_function(data), SomeException, None) is None:
    report_error('Something happened')
```

This comes from an idea in the rejected [PEP 463](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0463/).

[lambda to the Rescue](http://www.jjinux.com/2009/05/python-lambda-to-rescue.html) presents the same idea.